# How to insert an object infront of params object[]

Tags: c#

```
public class bar:foo
{
    public bar(int something, params object[] parameters)
        :base(something, parameters) //foo will receive {int, object[]}, not what i want
    {
    }
}

public class foo
{
    public foo(params object[] parameters)
    {
    }
}
```

so basically i would like to append one more object infront of the params array which i pass into the base class. Lets say I call `bar(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` i want foo to `receive {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` as params instead of {1, {2, 3, 4, 5}} which is what the code above is giving me.

Comment: Then create an array that contains `something` follower by the contents of `parameters`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Usually arrays are frowned upon. A better solution would use a LinkedList which provides ways for adding front

Édit

If you need to keep the variable parameters then you can use the .Union.ToArray() method available on c# arrays

Comment: dont think you can create a list in the super constructor

Comment: Do you have to use variable arrays?

Comment: Arrays have .Union. Would it help?

Comment: nope..union returns System.Linq.Enumerable.UnionIterator<object>

Comment: nvm. i think .Union.ToArray worked. Thanks. Modify the answer and i will accept it

Comment: I think there is a ToArray you can call

Comment: You don't want to use `Union`, you want to use `Concat`. Union does not concatenate two collections, it returns their union which is definitely not the same. As an example, try passing 3 as the int value, and 1,2,3,4,5 as the array contents and see what union does. Also try passing 3,3,3,3,3 as the array contents and see what union does. Union does a distinct operation. Concat merely concatenates.

Answer (score 7):

The solution is to create a new array that contains the first element + the elements from the original array, and pass the new array to the other method.

You can do that by creating a new array that holds the first parameter, and using [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx) to create a collection containing this parameter and the original array, and then turning that collection back into an array.

This expression would do it:

```
new object[] { something }.Concat(parameters).ToArray()
```

Thus your constructor definition would look like this:

```
public bar(int something, params object[] parameters)
    :base(new object[] { something }.Concat(parameters).ToArray())
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Old school:

- Create array [N + 1]
- Copy the first parameter
- Copy/Append the params array, after that.

Sometimes you don't need LINQ, where the size of the arrays is known in this case.

```
public static T[] Append<T>(this T first, params T[] items)
{
    T[] result = new T[items.Length + 1];

    result[0] = first;

    items.CopyTo(result, 1);

    return result;
}
```

(For very old school use Object instead of T)

Answer (score 0):

I like an extension; bit of both answers so far:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static object[] PrependToParamArray(this object me, params object[] args)
    {
        return new[] {me}.Concat(args).ToArray();
    }
}
```